# 'popular' in documentation

Tags: discussion, bug

In documentation when 'popular' tab is selected, the tags are ordered based on the number of topics each tag has got (screenshot below).

[image]

In the main page of each tag, it looks 'popular' tab orders each topic based on cumulative score of the examples that each topic has (screenshot below).

[image]

I see an inconsistency here, shouldn't the topics in each tag be ordered based on the number of examples rather than the score?

Comment: And here I thought _popular_ meant _most viewed_.

Comment: I find unstructured documentation a drag... the "popular" just gets more popular specially since the documentation isn't indexed by search engines (unless they changed something).

Comment: @Braiam I've been getting SOD in search results through Google lately when looking for plagiarism and students have reported getting results too

Comment: @JGreenwell well, I presume that my information is obsolete then.

Comment: The ordering of e.g. the Java documentation is *horrible*. It puts Array creation as the single most important topic of Java. WTF? Same for R - `%>%` is the most important R feature, who needs packages?

Comment: See also: [my feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331804/tutorial-style-list-for-documentation), [this feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329743/add-table-of-contents-or-tag-outline-section-to-introductory-topic), [this feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315160/more-hierarchical-structure-needed-for-documentation-topics), and [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331928/why-is-documentation-not-ordered-in-any-discernible-way#comment380690_331928) -- Docs.SO ordering needs a do-over

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I don't think it's saying Array creation is the most *important* topic, the popular tab is saying it's the most *popular*. Now, that's not to say the ordering is not crazy, but certainly sane people can agree that votes are one indication of popularity. I do agree with Jeffrey's comment that views should also be weighed in. There also needs to be a better default sort order in general.

Comment: @Lamda Ninja Yes Doc.SO needs a do-over. My question is more about inconsistency in the term 'popular' in documentation.